# Anylogic, how to simulate a machine set up that runs every time that an entering agent A has a parameter that differs from the last agent B served?

Tags: anylogic

I have Agent B / Agent A / Agent A type of agents in a queue waiting for a service (delay). But I need that when it's time to change from Agent A to Agent B, ocurrs a machine set up. How do you usually handle this situation?

I tried, with no success, making variables and checking conditions On enter in the delay. I'm new to AnyLogic, so any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Downtime` block allows to model changeovers for `Service` blocks. Read the help and explore all the tutorials and example models that use it to learn how it works.